How do hearing aids react to induction hobs?
I wear hearing aids, and since I got an induction hob, I notice that when I use the 'Power' setting, my hearing aids will start "buzzing" the closer I am to the hob. This does not always happen, just sometimes- I can't spot a pattern.
I presumed, also after googling this, that this has to do with some magnetic part of the technology. I once forgot to remove my hearing aids when I went for an MRI- after taking two steps out of the changing cabin, a massive buzz alerted me of my oversight (but the MRI wasn't turned on yet). So given that the MRI is essentially a big magnet, that tracks. But then, wouldn't microwaves, mobile phones or X-ray machines cause the same effect?
How does the hob / stove affect the hearing aid? What part of the technology in the hearing aid is affected, and what exactly does the hob emit?

will be specific to a particular hearing aid - not all will have identical design issues and same applies to hobs - some are built better than others...

MRIs and Induction heaters are magnetic fields.  Microwaves, mobile phones, and X-ray machines produce particles/waves on the electromagnetic spectrum, basically light at different energy levels.  These things would not act the same.

Do you have "hearing loop" enabled in your hearing aids? Hearing loop is specifically for picking up magnetic fields. If not, most likely just leaking audio-frequency radiation -- check the radiation standard for induction heaters.
